# SQL query return only unique results

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query which is working correctly...

```
SELECT *
FROM
    wp_rg_lead
    INNER JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail ON
            wp_rg_lead.id=wp_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
WHERE wp_rg_lead.form_id = '7'
and  cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
```

I would like to modify this to only return unique records.  The problem I have is that each 'entry' is actually made up of several like so....

```
id  |  form_id  |  entry_id  |    value
--------------------------------------------
1        1            75          red
2        1            75          broken
3        1            75          apple
4        7            33          yellow
5        7            33          faulty
6        7            33          banana
7        7            33          ripe
8        7            22          red
9        7            22          strawberry
10       7            22          broken
11       7            22          squashed
```

Using the above data I would only want it to return 2 results

Comment: What two results do you want it to return? The table of results doesn't make sense you're select in you're where the form_id='7' but it returns records with 1 in it?

Comment: I am building the results and then plan on grouping them before doing a count so I don't think it matters which result it returns

Comment: Do Group By on the columns that make the entry unique, and use MAX() or some other aggregate on the columns that don't matter.

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Do you want the value column returned? Are you only expecting a row for form_id=7 and entry_id=33 and entry_id=22 returned that I think is the 2 results that are unique for form_id=7? I'm still not sure what you'd want as you're 2 results.

Comment: your query can't return the results you display. What is the question, how to produce a working query?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT distinct form_id
FROM wp_rg_lead INNER JOIN
     wp_rg_lead_detail
     ON wp_rg_lead.id = wp_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
WHERE cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day;
```

If you want an entire arbitrary row, it looks like you are using Postgres, so you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT distinct on (form_id) *
FROM wp_rg_lead INNER JOIN
     wp_rg_lead_detail
     ON wp_rg_lead.id = wp_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
WHERE cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
ORDER BY form_id, id;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only bring back one row with just form_id=7 in it? You're selecting distinct form_id and the where is where form_id='7'

Comment: @BS123 . . . Yes.  That is strange.  The OP has this `where` clause in the question and suggested that it produced the results.  Clearly it didn't.

Comment: Yes the question made it seem like it returned those results but wouldn't because the where clause form_id=7 only.